# Benzilic rearangment

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Why does benzilic rearrangment occurs? Is there any explanation?

[image]

Comment: That's the wrong question to ask. As with any reaction, it takes place because the kinetics and thermodynamics are favorable.

Answer (score 2):

We can perform a very crude and very basic analysis of reactant and product to determine what is different and whether this corresponds to something more stable or not.

The difference is that one $\ce{C=O}$ double bond has been sacrificed to create two $\ce{C-O}$ single bonds. In terms of standardised bond enthalpies, two $\ce{C-O}$ single bonds are more stable than one $\ce{C=O}$ double bond.

Comment: Deprotonation of carboxylic acid should pull equilibrium to the product side too, imo.